# How much minimum space Ubuntu 12.04 installation requires

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have a Windows installation and only one partition in my hard disk AS IN there is only C drive.

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 alongside it but i am not sure how much disk space i must allocate for Ubuntu. 
Actualy i just have 12GB space left on my harddisk and i am wondering if an ubuntu installation can be effectively made in such a small space or not.
Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine. The Ubuntu Official Documentation recommends at least 5GB of hard drive space when installing with a desktop, which I assume you're doing.

You can read more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/minimum-hardware-reqts.html